# List files (recursively) which have no matching pair

Tags: bash

I have a set of files in multiple directories. Most of them have a related pair with a different extension and the same base name. The related files are always within the same directory. I need to list only files (and path) without pairs within a directory including all sub directories. How can I do that in bash?

```
file1.xxx
file1.yyy

file2.xxx
file2.zzz

file3.xxx
file3.aaa

file4.xxx
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you can strip off the file extensions, `uniq -u` will identify unique base names.

Comment: Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the files under your directory and then count how many matches you can find of their whole name in the same tree directory which has the same path name (excluding extension).

If your file matches with less or one names, that means it has not "companion" files:

```
for f in $(find -type f); do 
    c=$(find -wholename "$(echo $f | rev | cut --complement -d . -f 1 | rev).*" | wc -l);  
    if [ "$c" -le "1" ]; then echo $f; fi; 
done
```

**Edit:**

It might more readable if the pattern composition is performed in a different line:

```
for f in $(find -type f); do 
    compPattern="$(echo $f | rev | cut --complement -d . -f 1 | rev).*" 
    c=$(find -wholename "$compPattern" | wc -l);
    if [ "$c" -le "1" ]; then echo $f; fi; 
done
```

**Edit (2)**

To avoid parsing the output of the `find` you can use read:

```
find -type f | while read f; do 
    if [ $(find -wholename "$(echo $f | rev | cut --complement -d . -f 1 | rev).*" | wc -l) -le "1" ]; then echo $f; fi; 
done
```

**Edit(3)**

To handle special chars, spaces etc. you can use the following.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f ; do
    c=$(find -wholename "$(echo $f | rev | cut --complement -d . -f 1 | rev).*" | wc -l);
    if [ "$c" -le "1" ]; then echo $f; fi;
done < <(find -type f -print0)
```

Comment: Shouldn't parse find.

Comment: @Pablo Why not simply: `find ./ -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/\..*//' | sort | uniq -u`

Comment: @MikeSkril I thought you wanted the full paths?

Comment: Seems to be not working with special characters in the file name.

Comment: @MikeSkril Thats why you don't parse the results of find using bash loops.

Comment: @MikeSkril Actually, that's a bit misleading, you could but you would need to use while read and `-print0` flag for find. I'd still advise against it though.

Comment: @123  Shouldn't `find -type f | while read f; do ... done` fix the problem?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo No since you are still splitting on default IFS, which can be contained in filenames.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Do you mind if I edit your question to add a solution for all filenames?

Comment: @MikeSkril Added edit to the question, note this will still be very slow though, due to the fact that there are multiple processes forked every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @123 Thanks to you! Btw, time performance could be significantly improved by keeping the result of an unfiltered find into a variable and use grep to lookup the matching pairs, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

You could use find and pipe to perl to sort the data

```
find . -type f -print0 |\
perl -0 -l012 -ne 'if(/.*\/(.*)\./){$x{$1}++;$y{$1}=$_}
}{for(keys %x){print $y{$_} if $x{$_}==1}'
```

This adds the name with no suffix to a hash and incremements for each match, whilst adding the full line to another hash with the same key.

In the end it just checks which have a single match and prints.

As the filenames are null delimited it should work with all filenames.

Comment: Short and sweet!